# "einsum"ize outer products of each col of A and row of B and store in a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

Even though I've found a few ways to do this, I'd like to fish for more concise and/or efficient ways to do the following: Suppose we have two arrays

```
A = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
B = np.arange(-5, 7).reshape(3, 4)
```

What I would like to do is to compute the outer products and place them in a 3D array `C` with the resulting shape `(4,4,3)` such that the relation

```
C[:, :, k] == A[:, [k]] @ B[[k]]
```

should hold true for `k=0,1,2`.

The resulting array `C` is

```
array([[[  0.,  -1.,   6.],
        [  0.,   0.,   8.],
        [  0.,   1.,  10.],
        [  0.,   2.,  12.]],

       [[-15.,  -4.,  15.],
        [-12.,   0.,  20.],
        [ -9.,   4.,  25.],
        [ -6.,   8.,  30.]],

       [[-30.,  -7.,  24.],
        [-24.,   0.,  32.],
        [-18.,   7.,  40.],
        [-12.,  14.,  48.]],

       [[-45., -10.,  33.],
        [-36.,   0.,  44.],
        [-27.,  10.,  55.],
        [-18.,  20.,  66.]]])
```

Is there a way to enter this in the `np.einsum` formulation? Other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: I'd change the `B` shape to (3,5) so there's less chance of mixing up the two size 4 dimensions. The result should then be (4,5,3)

Comment: Then the einsum expression almost writes itself 'ij,jk->ikj'

Comment: @hpaulj Yes for some reason I've made myself believe that the output should also alphabetical. I guess time to head to the pub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), it would be -

```
np.einsum('ij,jl->ilj',A,B)
```

There's no sum-reduction happening, so one could simply extend those to `3D` and hence leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) as well -

```
A[:,None]*B.T
```

Comment: Oh, I thought the output should be in alphabetical order. Damn, then it is indeed trivial. I was using the broadcasting already but thanks anyway. One less stupid prejudice.